# Join On Text Fields In Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, join

I am unable to change DDL for the tables, but I need to join on two `text` fields.  I get an error of

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Below is sample DDL that illustrates my issue, how do I overcome?

```
Declare @Table1 Table(id text,name nvarchar(200))
Insert Into @Table1 (id, name) Values
('123', 'Joe'), ('222.00', 'Jim')
Declare @Table2 Table (id text,green nvarchar(200))
Insert Into @Table2 (id, green) Values
('123', 'JDSKLJS'), ('222.00', 'KLJKLJJKL')
Select
*
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast `text` fields as `varchar(max)`

> ```
> Declare @Table1 Table(id text,name nvarchar(200))
> Insert Into @Table1 (id, name) Values
> ('123', 'Joe'), ('222.00', 'Jim')
> Declare @Table2 Table (id text,green nvarchar(200))
> Insert Into @Table2 (id, green) Values
> ('123', 'JDSKLJS'), ('222.00', 'KLJKLJJKL');
>
> Select
> *
> FROM @Table1 t1
> INNER JOIN @Table2 t2
> ON cast(t1.id as varchar(max)) = cast(t2.id as varchar(max))
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id     | name | id     | green    
> :----- | :--- | :----- | :--------
> 123    | Joe  | 123    | JDSKLJS  
> 222.00 | Jim  | 222.00 | KLJKLJJKL
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9032d412816ac69b8e3483bc5fc3cb0e)*

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert (in the join) to a smaller data type:

```
Select *
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2
ON CONVERT(varchar(8000),t1.id) = CONVERT(varchar(8000),t2.id)
```

Or some smaller number that you know will make the match unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2
ON CAST(t1.id AS varchar(max)) = CAST(t2.id AS varchar(max))
```

Note that the performance will be pretty awful, so I wouldn't do this in any sort of production code; refactor the schema to better support what you're trying to do.